# Resource cached with max-age=0

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control, http-caching

I have a resource that is served with the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 05 May 2021 12:22:58 GMT
etag: "1609459200000-gzip"
expires: Wed, 05 May 2021 12:22:58 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 01 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Yesterday we updated this resource and we noted that about 10% of the traffic is, 24h later, still using the stale resource. In those cases, the browser uses the old cached resource without hitting the server (to revalidate or get a fresh version).

Why some browsers don't honor `max-age` and don't revalidate (or get a fresh version) of this resource?

Is it mandatory to use, in this case, `no-cache` to force a revalidation?

If I want to use the cached resource and revalidate only after 10 seconds, will this be enough for any modern browser?

`Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=10`